# Blob data fetching is too slow

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I'm storing 180 tiled image data into MySQL database. Each tiles about 10KB.

When I try to fetch ALL of the tiles from the MySQL database with ONE connection and SINGLE query, it takes 200ms and it is very slow for me.

Is there any way to make it faster?

This is my "**filedata**" table. (I've tried MyISAM and INNODB. Result is the same :()

```
id (int) **PrimaryKey**
layerid (int)
channelid (int)
stratumid (int)
x (int)
y (int)
tiledata (MEDIUMBLOB)
```

And this is my console application for testing the query.

```
Console.ReadKey();

Stopwatch swx = new Stopwatch();
swx.Start();

    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=trying;Uid=root;Pwd=;Encrypt=false;AllowUserVariables=True;UseCompression=True;");
    conn.Open();


Console.WriteLine("Connection open.");

swx.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Conn Open Time = " + swx.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

Console.ReadKey();
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
MySqlCommand com = conn.CreateCommand();
com.CommandText = "SELECT filedata FROM filedata where layerid = '5'";
MySqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    byte[] b = (byte[])reader[0];
}
reader.Close();
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Time= " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
Console.ReadKey();
```

My computer is;

Processor: i7 2,67 Ghz,
RAM: 6 GB,
HDD: 1 TB SSD.

Comment: What if you run the query on your database directly? How fast is it then?

Comment: @Patrick Server=127.0.0.1. OP: you'll need to find the slow part. If it is the database, consider using the file system.

Comment: Everything is on this computer. And i'm NOT using WAMP for a website. I'm using it just for the MysqlServer :)

Comment: "SELECT filedata FROM filedata where layerid = '5'" results 182 and takes 0.0109 sec.

Comment: I assume it is `Select tiledata`?

Comment: yes it is Select tiledata

Comment: Is this rather slow timimg just for a first time or is it consistently slow?

Comment: Hi again. it is consistently slow. This code results in 200 - 210ms every time i run it.